# error geocoding API

Tags: c#, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am trying to use google geocoding. If i just type

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true
```

it gives me right output. I am trying to use this with a amazon proxy server and it gives

```
{ "error_message" : "The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }
```

This the code

```
http://ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com/OsProxy/getpage.aspx?p=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks
Rashmi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [URL-encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) your parameters.  Consider the URL you're using:

```
http://ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com/OsProxy/getpage.aspx?p=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true
```

This is parsed as:

```
http://ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com/OsProxy/getpage.aspx?
    p=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&
    sensor=true
```

That is, you're passing the `sensor` parameter to `amazonws.com`, not to `googleapis.com`.

Since the only parameter to `amazonws.com` should be the full URL, encode that URL so it reaches `amazonws.com` as a single parameter to be passed through to `googleapis.com`:

```
http://ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com/OsProxy/getpage.aspx?p=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.googleapis.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fgeocode%2Fjson%3Faddress%3D1600%2BAmphitheatre%2BParkway%2C%2BMountain%2BView%2C%2BCA%26sensor%3Dtrue
```